# How to get the clicked row's id value?

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, onclick, row

I generated a table by getting the values from database.
I set the primary key value to the row's id value, I have button in that row also.
How to get the respective id value when I click the button.

```
  while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($get_pack))
    {
       echo"<tr id='<php echo $pack[id];?>'>";
       echo'<td> <input name="edit_pack" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit_pack()"/></td>';
     }

function edit_pack()
   {
   alert("package editing")
   alert(this.id)
   }
```

Comment: `echo"<tr id='<php echo $pack[id];?>'>";` ---> `echo"<tr id='".$pack[$id]."'>";`

Comment: by the way the first echo statement is wrong. You dont need to put <?php tags in there. echo"<tr id='".$pack[$id]."'>";

Answer (score 3):

Try this for a pure JavaScript solution:

```
function edit_pack() {
    alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.id);
}
```

The first `parentNode` will get the `<td>`, the second will get the `<tr>`. We then get the `id` attribute.

Alternatively the syntax is a little nicer if you're using jQuery:

```
function edit_pack() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr')[0].id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as the parameter of the js function.

```
echo'<td> <input name="edit_pack" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit_pack( ' .$pack['id']. ' )"/></td>';
```

Then in the js

```
function edit_pack(id){ 
  alert(id);
}
```

Comment: By giving like that it gives notice errors...  Notice: Undefined variable: id in F:\wamp\www\Trading\Admin\packages.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: in F:\wamp\www\Trading\Admin\packages.php on line 32

Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in F:\wamp\www\Trading\Admin\packages.php on line 36

Comment: I think thats a mistake on my part. Try .$pack['id']. with the id surrounded by qoutemarks.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the value in the JS call

PHP

```
while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($get_pack))
{
   echo '<tr id="'.$pack[id].'">';
   echo '<td> <input name="edit_pack" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit_pack('.$pack[id].')"/></td>';
 }
```

Javascript

```
function edit_pack(id) {
   alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need

```
while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($get_pack))
{
   echo"<tr id='<php echo $pack[id];?>'>";
   echo'<td> <input parentrow_id='<php echo $pack[id];?>' name="edit_pack" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit_pack(this.parentrow_id)"/></td>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jquery then do as follows:

```
 while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($get_pack))
 {
    echo"<tr id='<php echo $pack[id];?>'>";
    echo'<td> <input name="edit_pack" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit_pack('<?php echo $pack[id];?>')"/></td>';
 }

function edit_pack(pack_id)
{
   alert("package editing");
   alert(pack_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("[name=edit_pack]").click(function(){
           alert($(this).parents("tr").attr('id'));
       });
    });
 </script>
<?php
       echo"<table name='test'>";
       echo"<tr id='20'>";
       echo'<td> <input name="edit_pack" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit_pack()"/></td>';
       echo"</tr>";
       echo"</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while($pack = mysql_fetch_array($get_pack)){
       echo"<tr id='$pack[id]'>";
       echo " <td> <input name='edit_pack' type='button' value='Edit' onclick='edit_pick($pack[id]);'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
   }
```

Your can pass argument JavaScript function